# Escaping special characters in a RDN for LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, openldap

Escape invalid characters in a distinguished name is done with a leading slash ('\'). For example, the distinguished name above should be:

"CN=Surname\, Lastname,OU=Users,DC=Foo,DC=net"
    According to section 2.4 of See RFC 4514: Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP): String Representation of Distinguished Names, the characters , ", #, +, ,, ;, <, =, >, and \ can be escaped by a leading slash.

to do the same,

the below approach has been used :

```
    public String escapeRDN(String dn) {
            String attributeValue; 
            StringBuffer escapedDN = new StringBuffer();
            String subStr;
            int i=0;
            int index =-1;
            int nextIndex=-1;
            if(dn!=null)
            index=dn.indexOf("=");
            if(index!=-1){
                index = dn.indexOf("=");
                escapedDN.append(dn.substring(0,index+1));
                for(i=index+1;i<dn.length();i++){
                    nextIndex = dn.substring(i).indexOf("=");
                    if(nextIndex!=-1){
                        subStr = dn.substring(i,i+nextIndex);
                        int len=subStr.length();
                        int j=len-1;
                        int commaIndex=0;
                        char ch[] = subStr.toCharArray();
                        while(j>0){
                            if(ch[j]==','){
                                commaIndex=len-j;
                                break;
                            }
                            j--;

                        }
                        attributeValue = subStr.substring(0,commaIndex);
                        attributeValue = Rdn.escapeValue(attributeValue);
                        escapedDN.append(attributeValue);
                        escapedDN.append(subStr.substring(commaIndex));
                        escapedDN.append("=");
                        i=i+nextIndex;


                    }
                    else{
                        subStr = dn.substring(i);
                        subStr = Rdn.escapeValue(subStr);
                        escapedDN.append(subStr);
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid DN");
            }

            dn=escapedDN.toString();

            return dn;
        }
```

with the above approach,

when the input dn is suppose :

String dn = "cn=abc,abc,sn=pqr=,pqr,ou=org";

then the output appears as follows :

cn=abc\,abc,sn=pqr=\,pqr,ou=org

thus, with the above approach '=' in attribute value does not gets escpaed.

Can someone please help me by suggesting appropriate approach for the same.

Comment: In the above approach, the attribute values are ectracted, using the parsing the dn value by extracting the index value of '=' due to which .. to escape '=' in my attribute value facing the issue

Comment: the line  commaIndex=len-j; is actually,  commaIndex=j; .. a slight mistake in above code..

Comment: Why would you try to do this yourself? Use LDAP SDK. https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/DN.html